# Request to find a quote "every new mathematical notation opens a whole new possibilities"

Tags: notation

In one of the book on mathematics (it wasn't specifically on the notations though) I've read something like "[invention of] every new mathematical notation opens a whole new possibilities/abilities/opportunities". It has been said by some well-known mathematician and the author of the book himself quoted (or retold) original author's utterance. Since then there were many other books and papers I've read so far, so I've totally lost any capabilities to trace it back in my brain. I'm not sure if I can ask this question here but if someone accidentally remember who might have said it - that would be really nice! Thank you all.

Comment: I find this quote a bit exaggerating.

Comment: I can't but agree that the notation affects the way you think and what the thoughts you can think.

Comment: history of math and science stack.

Comment: Exactly! Would be great if someone can move my question there.